# How to check if a website supports HTTP/2 in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I'm trying to get `101 Switching Protocol` response by upgrading the connnection to HTTP/2 via `Socket`. I've tried big web that support HTTP/2 such as `google.com` and `twitter.com`, None of them that give a proper response, here's the approach:

```
import socket
import ssl

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
context = ssl.create_default_context()
context.set_ciphers(cipher)
sock.connect(('twitter.com', 443))
sock = context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname='twitter.com')
sock.sendall(bytes('GET h2://twitter.com/ HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: twitter.com\r\nConnection: Upgrade, HTTP2-Settings\r\nUpgrade: h2\r\nHTTP2-Settings: \r\nAlt-Svc: h2=":443"\r\n\r\n',encoding='utf-8'))

sock.settimeout(5)
sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1)
line = str(sock.recv(10000))
print(line)
```

Upgrading the HTTP/1 connection to HTTP/2; giving `400` bad request, not what I'm expecting `101`.

```
sock.connect(('www.google.com', 443))
sock = context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname='www.google.com')
sock.sendall(bytes('GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.google.com\r\nConnection: Upgrade, HTTP2-Settings\r\nUpgrade: h2\r\nHTTP2-Settings: \r\n\r\n',encoding='utf-8'))
```

I've also tried to set `ALPN` protocol manually but `google.com` and `twitter.com` give different response:

```
context.set_alpn_protocols(['h2'])
```

for `google.com` there's frame response:

```
b'\x00\x00\x12\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00d\x00\x04\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00\x06\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0f\x00\x01'
```

but `twitter.com` giving empty response frame:

```
b''
```

The reason for this is, i had to perform checks based on `wordlist` that contains list of website. How can i properly check if website supports for HTTP/2 in Python?

**Attachment**:
[Twitter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWPMC.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you do need to set the `context.set_alpn_protocols(['h2'])`
and you can check if you successfully negotiated with `sock.selected_alpn_protocol()`.

Unfortunately, if you want to actually test an http call, you need to encode the header (get, host, etc.).   rfc7540 section 4 and section 6.2 detail the requirement.  a python library like h2 can help with the encoding as well as properly encode and decode the other sadly necessary http2 chatter.

The whole connection upgrade thing is not used by web browsers, so it is not unexpected that websites don't support it.  Once you have an alpn h2 negotiated tls stream, a *properly* encoded

```
GET / HTTP/2
Host: twitter.com
```

should be all you need.  That is the reason twitter just closed the socket.  I suspect the google frame sent back (if you used hpack to decode) would say something like "I don't understand".

Comment: The "I don't understand" part at the end, give me a chuckle.  Now it's clear that after alpn-h2 is already negotiated, i should've just directly sent h2 frame. So in the end: just replace ```bytes()``` to ```hpack.Encoder()``` right?. Thanks for the great stuff!

Comment: @Xav it is more complicated then I described.  fortunately, the authors of hpack have a  full library that does just what you want called h2.   They even have an example using raw sockets that you should be able to adapt to your needs.  gone are the days of simple 7bit ascii protocols.   https://python-hyper.org/projects/hyper-h2/en/stable/plain-sockets-example.html

Comment: Perfect, i've been stumbled upon a problem where the hpack unable to decode response:
```Unable to decode HPACK integer representation from <memory at 0x0>```, this seems another source to try. Thanks.. @toppk